Facing Memory Issues in Google Colab When TESTING/training TensorFlow Time-Series Model
training often crashes due to Out of Memory (OOM) errors, this seems to be a fairly novel problem after I moved some functions into classes in a utils.py script and made slight changes to the archtiecture, suddenly things stopped working (I think it may even be a TF library update) I have an atypical experimental setup where a new instance of the model is made for a full training and prediction, and the non-gpu ram steadily increases despite not needing past versions of the object. GPU memory strangely barely moves.
My 'testing' loop is the following:
def rolling_test(model_class, feature_matrix, feature_vector, chunk, predictions, sequence_length=None, model_name=""):
    logger.info(f'Starting {model_name} test')
    forecasts, actuals, forecast_dates = [], [], []
    t = 0

    feature_matrix = feature_matrix.astype(np.float32)
    feature_vector = feature_vector.astype(np.float32)

    if len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')) > 0:
        device = '/device:GPU:0'
    else:
        device = '/CPU:0'

    while t < predictions:
        end_idx = -(predictions - t) if t != predictions - 1 else None
        start_idx = -(chunk - t) if t < chunk else None

        X_fit = feature_matrix.iloc[start_idx:end_idx]
        y_fit = feature_vector.iloc[start_idx:end_idx]
        X_test = feature_matrix.iloc[end_idx:end_idx+1] if end_idx is not None else feature_matrix.iloc[-1:]
        y_test = feature_vector.iloc[end_idx:end_idx+1] if end_idx is not None else feature_vector.iloc[-1:]

        logger.info(f'Test {t+1}/{predictions}')

        if y_test.empty:
            logger.info(f"No data for {t}")
            t += 1
            del X_fit, y_fit, X_test, y_test
            gc.collect()
            continue

        try:
            # Reinitialize the model for each iteration
            model = model_class(sequence_length=sequence_length)
            
            with tf.device(device):
                model.fit(X_fit.values, y_fit.values)
                forecast = model.predict().flatten()

            forecasts.append(round(forecast[0], 4))
            actuals.append(round(y_test.values.flatten()[0], 4))
            forecast_dates.append(y_test.index[0])

        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"An error occurred: {traceback.format_exc()}")

        finally:
            if hasattr(model, 'cleanup'):
                model.cleanup()

            # Clear model and other resources
            del model
            del X_fit, y_fit, X_test, y_test
            tf.keras.backend.clear_session()  # Clear the session to free up memory
            gc.collect()

        t += 1

    return {
        'forecasts': forecasts,
        'actuals': actuals,
        'dates': forecast_dates
    }


which is accessed via a colab notebook:
model_name = f'TFT-GRU{model_name_suffix}'
with contextlib.redirect_stdout(sys.__stdout__):
    print(f'Training and rolling test for {model_name}')
raw_metrics[model_name] = rolling_test(
    TFT_GRU, X, y, chunk=(window + predictions), predictions=predictions, sequence_length=sequence_length, model_name=model_name
)
levels_metrics[model_name] = reconstruct_levels(target_vector,raw_metrics[model_name])

del model_name
gc.collect()

I’ve tried various strategies for managing memory, like limiting GPU memoru growth, deletion of variables, closing sessions, etc, and I still face memory-related crashes, especially when the dataset is large or when the model is complex.
Environment:
Google Colab
TensorFlow Version: 2.16 (possible reason for memory issues)
GPU: NVIDIA T4
Questions:
I can provide more detailed code snippets or logs showing the memory errors. Any help or would be greatly appreciated!
